# STL loading and incorrect world matrix access

Tags: javascript, three.js

for a three.js project I have I have run into a few problems loading vertices from an STL and adequately converting them to world coordinates. It seems the matrix isn't being applied properly and, I think, it might be related to the loading mechanism itself.

```
loader.load( './assets/models/trajan_print.stl', function ( geometry ) {
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  mesh.name = "target";
  mesh.position.set( 0, - 300, - 400 );
  mesh.rotation.set( - Math.PI / 2, 0, Math.PI );
  mesh.scale.set( 5, 5, 5 );
  //mesh.castShadow = true;
  //mesh.receiveShadow = true;
  mesh.visible = false;
  SCENE.add( mesh );
  model.setTargets(mesh);
} );
```

the important function to note is the last one. `model.setTargets(mesh)`. I'm interested in the vertices of the object in world coordinates and that's what that function does... kinda of:

```
    setTargets(mesh){
        this.matrixWorld = mesh.matrixWorld;  //THIS WORKS, PRINTING IT REVEALS VALUES TRANSLATION/SCALE/ROTATION THAT MATCH THE MODEL'S
        var buffer = mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array;
        for(var i = 0; i < buffer.length /3; i = i + 3){
            var point = new THREE.Vector3(buffer[i], buffer[i+1],buffer[i+2]);
            point.applyMatrix4(this.matrixWorld);//DOES NOT WORK
            this.unassignedVertices.push(point);
        }
    }
```

Now if I do the exact same operation outside of this function it will work as intended. This one is only called if this.unassignedVertices so it was my way around the fact that I needed to wait for the asynchronous load to happen.

```
    insertParticle(part) {
        var point = this.unassignedVertices.pop();
        point.applyMatrix4(this.matrixWorld); //THIS WORKS BUT HERE BUT WHY?
        part.setTargetPoint(point);
        this.octree.add(part);
        this.particles.add(part);
    }
```

Problem number two, relates back to `setTargets(mesh)` I seem to only be loading around only half of the vertices from  `mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array`. Now this can actually be caused by other parts in the code and I think that is something that falls outside the scope of a SO question so my question is if anything on that function could be responsible for it? Am I loading it improperly, am I converting it wrong, am I skipping points?

As for further context : the model loads and displays just fine if I remove the visible = false tag.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so if anyone runs into this problem. The array will have duplicate positions as not all of them refer to vertices (probably). Simple case of if(position.x ==  ... cleans it right up to what's expected.